# Pre and Post, treated and un treated but from same subject

Tags: repeated-measures, clinical-trials

A treatment was given to one hand of a subject, and a single outcome metric is measured for both hands, twice pre and several times post treatment.

What is best practice for assessing effectiveness of treatment?

Treated and Untreated "groups" really are paired.

Comment: Is the hand assigned to treatment chosen at random? Is the outcome variable related to handedness (i.e., whether you prefer left or right hand)?

Answer (score 3):

For each time the metric is measured, take the difference of the measurements between the two hands. This gives you just one variable measured over time, which you can measure as repeated measures. You hypothesize that the mean value of this difference across subjects will change (or won't change) after the treatment.